# Laravel 8 API Subdomain Unreachable

Tags: laravel

I am trying to use `domain()` instead of `prefix()` for my API's endpoint. Im not able to reach this endpoint

**ENV**

```
API_DOMAIN=api.rest-api.test
```

**RoutServiceProvider.php**

```
        Route::domain(env('API_DOMAIN'))
            ->middleware('api')
            ->namespace($this->namespace)
            ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));
```

**API.php**

```
Route::get('/person', function(){
    $person = [
        'first-name' => 'Bob',
        'last-name' => 'Tables'
    ];

    return $person;
});
```

**Postman Error**

> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.rest-api.test

**EDIT :** I neglected to mention that this worked properly with the default `prefix()` option.

Comment: This error means the client was not able to connect to given address. try this `API_DOMAIN=http://api.rest-api.test`

Comment: @FaridVatani unfortunately that did not help

Comment: Did you configure the subdomains on the webserver?

Comment: env function only works on config file. Try add config on config/app.php, ``'app_domain' => env('API_DOMAIN'), ``. Cache the config ``php artisan config:cache``. Now you can call it on route, ``Route::domain(config('app.app_domain'))``

Comment: @FaridVatani that did the trick. Was watching a tutorial that was using Valet (Mac only) so their domains were auto mapped. On a Windows machine this will need to be done manually in `etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial I was watching was using Valet (Mac only) so their domains were mapped automatically. For Windows users, you will need to manually add domains to your `etc/hosts` file.